# Remove span from column with introtext

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

In my database, I have `my_table`, with column `introtext`.

Some of the records include a span, I'd like to remove:

```
<p><span style="line-height: 1.7142857148;">Text text text...</span></p>
```

And get instead something like:

```
<p>Text text text....</p>
```

I need an SQL query to do this automatically. I am trying this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET introtext= REPLACE('introtext', '<span style="line-height: 1.7142857148;">','')

UPDATE my_table
SET introtext= REPLACE('introtext', '</span>','')
```

This is returning the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

How can I build a query that removes the span from the introtext no matter what style or classes it has without this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just miss a ; after your first query, and you don't have to quote introtext:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET introtext= REPLACE(introtext, '<span style="line-height: 1.7142857148;">','');

UPDATE my_table
SET introtext= REPLACE(introtext, '</span>','');
```

Please see it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50b5d/1).